# Javascript StopWatch Wrong Reset Value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple vanilla JS stopwatch. Managed to make it work however when I click my reset button, the value returns my innerHTML change, however it flashes for a quick second before returning a value of 00:00:1 and not 00:00:00. I would have to click it two times before it resets correctly. However, when I pause my timer then reset, it works perfectly. Where is the flaw in my code?

Code:

```js
var status = 0;
var time = 0;

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pause);
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);


function start() {

  status = 1;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
  timer();


}

function pause() {
  status = 0;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function reset() {

  time = 0;
  status = 0;

  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = '00:00:00';
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function timer() {
  if (status == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      time++;
      var min = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
      var sec = Math.floor(time / 10 % 60);
      var mill = time % 10;

      if (min < 10) {
        min = '0' + min;
      }

      if (sec >= 60) {
        sec = sec % 60;
      }

      if (sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
      }

      document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = min + ':' + sec + ':' + mill;
      timer();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="label">00:00:00</h1>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am assuming that it is resetting it first and then stopping it, since then the stopwatch is not disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `setTimeout`, since it's scheduled to run each `100ms`, it will run once after you click reset (after a `100ms`). In order to prevent it from running after reset, you can store the timeout in a variable and stop it using `clearTimeout`:

```js
var status = 0;
var time = 0;
var t; // the timeout

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pause);
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);


function start() {

  status = 1;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
  timer();


}

function pause() {
  status = 0;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function reset() {

  time = 0;
  status = 0;
  clearTimeout(t); // stop the timeout
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = '00:00:00';
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function timer() {
  if (status == 1) {
    t = setTimeout(function() { // start the timeout
      time++;
      var min = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
      var sec = Math.floor(time / 10 % 60);
      var mill = time % 10;

      if (min < 10) {
        min = '0' + min;
      }

      if (sec >= 60) {
        sec = sec % 60;
      }

      if (sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
      }

      document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = min + ':' + sec + ':' + mill;
      timer();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="label">00:00:00</h1>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that I believe there is a slight latency and you aren't actually clearing the timeout that gets run when you start. It's good practice to keep track of the timeout ID and then clear it appropriately when you need to.

```js
var status = 0;
var time = 0;
var timeoutId;

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pause);
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);


function start() {

  status = 1;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
  timer();


}

function pause() {
  status = 0;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function reset() {

  time = 0;
  status = 0;
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);

  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = '00:00:00';
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function timer() {
  if (status == 1) {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      time++;
      var min = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
      var sec = Math.floor(time / 10 % 60);
      var mill = time % 10;

      if (min < 10) {
        min = '0' + min;
      }

      if (sec >= 60) {
        sec = sec % 60;
      }

      if (sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
      }

      document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = min + ':' + sec + ':' + mill;
      timer();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="label">00:00:00</h1>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its realy simple you have to remove the setTimeout callback function

```js
var timerObj = null; // NEW LINE
var status = 0;
var time = 0;

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pause);
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);


function start() {

  status = 1;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
  timer();


}

function pause() {
  status = 0;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
}

function reset() {
  clearTimeout(timerObj ); // new LINE
  status = 0;
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
  time = 0;
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = '00:00:00';
}

function timer() {
  if (status == 1) {
    timerObj = setTimeout(function() {   // changed LINE
      time++;
      var min = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
      var sec = Math.floor(time / 10 % 60);
      var mill = time % 10;

      if (min < 10) {
        min = '0' + min;
      }

      if (sec >= 60) {
        sec = sec % 60;
      }

      if (sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
      }

      document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = min + ':' + sec + ':' + mill;
      timer();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="label">00:00:00</h1>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```